# How to make Visual Studio 2010 display command line of build/deploy steps?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to make Visual Studio 2010 display the command line of each of the build/deploy steps? I'm running in to a problem deploying a SharePoint Web Part on a production server, but the deploy feature in VS works just fine. If I could see the commands that VS is running to deploy the web part I might be able to see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change **Verbosity** level. Go into the the **Tools->Options** menu, and go to **Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run**. You will find **MSBuild project build output verbosity** - this is setting for output window. You can change it to **Diagnostic** to see detailed output log. When you will build your project next time - you will find all outputs in **Output** window -> **Build**.